# can AVAssetReader be used to stream audio data over bluetooth/wifi?

Tags: ios, gksession, avassetreader

According to AVAssetReader [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAssetReader_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

```
AVAssetReader is not intended for use with real-time sources, and its performance is not guaranteed for real-time operations.
```

Yet I see [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11398997/avassetreader-to-audioqueuebuffer) of it working with the audio queue services.. which is real time isn't it? Can I use AVAssetReader to stream data and send it over GKSession or something?

Answer (score 0):

after extensive testing and development for several months.. I can claim that AVAssetReader indeed works just fine on real time and reliably so.. and it can easily integrate with GKSession to send packets over a network.